# How do I write multiple GetAsyncKeyState with C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My problem is where can I add this line of code:

`if( GetKeyState(VK_F2) & 0x8000 )`

I tried in different ways, but when I compile and run it and press the F1 or F2 key it executes all the functions. I want to call the F1 key functions when the key is pressed and F2 key when it is pressed. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Here is my code:

```
switch(uMsg)
{
case WM_INITDIALOG:
    {
        // do something here
        break;
    }
case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if( GetKeyState(VK_F1) & 0x8000 )

        if( GetKeyState(VK_F2) & 0x8000 )

        {

            // do something here

        }
        break;
    }
case WM_CLOSE:
    {
           // do something here
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: I think that in your case, where you want to do something when one key is pressed, else do another thing when another key is pressed, you should probably use the [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead. Also note that this comment includes a hint of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:) well my problem is solved after trying for sometime finally i got it the problem
was that little "break;" statement please look at the code its working flawless.
Thank you so very much for your time and help appreciated

```
case WM_TIMER:
    {
        if(GetKeyState(VK_F1) & 0x8000 )
    {
        MessageBoxA (NULL, TEXT ("This is a call from F1 key!"), TEXT("Test F1 key"), MB_OK );
    }

        //break; << this was the one that was giving me the problem 

         if(GetKeyState(VK_F2) & 0x8000 )
    {
        MessageBoxA (NULL, TEXT ("This is a call from F2 key!"), TEXT("Test F2 key"), MB_OK );
    }

        //if(GetKeyState(VK_F3) & 0x8000 ) << i can add multi VK_ keys here

        break; // << should be here
    }
case WM_CLOSE:
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple points:

1. Are you sure you want to poll like this? Maybe you want to be responding to notifications when the user presses these keys (WM_KEYDOWN for example) instead of polling periodically? Your code has the problem that it can easily miss if you press & release F1 between `WM_TIMER`s.
2. You should probably be using `GetKeyState`, as Joachim Pileborg says. `GetAsyncKeyState` works on the state of the keyboard at the time of the call; `GetKeyState` works on the state of the keyboard when the current message was sent. This tends to keep things more tightly synchronized. That said, if you're polling in `WM_TIMER`, it probably doesn't matter so much.
3. You are only checking if the return value is non-zero, which is not how this function works. The return value is a bitmask. From the documentation:

> If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up.
>
> If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled. A key, such as the CAPS LOCK key, is toggled if it is turned on. The key is off and untoggled if the low-order bit is 0. A toggle key's indicator light (if any) on the keyboard will be on when the key is toggled, and off when the key is untoggled.

Thus, to check for <kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
if( GetKeyState(VK_F1) & 0x8000 )
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: i didn't knew that so where should i write the next code if( GetKeyState(VK_F2) & 0x8000 )as you know i am new to programming language anyway thank you for your help and time appreciated

Comment: You need a solid basis for the programming language in order to make much use of this website. If you don't understand the answers, then there's not much point posting questions. Your problem is not about checking for keys pressed, your problem is about fundamental C++ syntax.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, have a look at [GetKeyboardState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299.aspx), so that you can check the state of multiple keys at the same time without having to make multiple function calls.

Comment: Thank you sir i was thinking about that how to make just one function instead of a multiple function calls might take some time:) but i am eager to learn it anyway appreciate your help and time thank you